# Value is textbox disappears after it comes back to view

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I have a datagrid, where I have styled the column headers to have a textbox in them so that I can perform filtering.

I enter some text in the textbox of the last column, then resize my window such that I will no longer see the last column. After that I resize my window again to show the last column. The value in the textbox disappears - as if the textbox control is regenerated again.

How can I retain the value?

Comment: Can you show the xaml and cs code?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling column virtualization solved the problem for me..

Comment: [Who wants some Milk and Cookies](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fs-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com%2F736x%2F55%2F13%2F11%2F551311ddd3223be935090ae4fb8e8269.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pinterest.com%2Fpin%2F239394536417785090%2F&docid=N7jcYTOHK0HyHM&tbnid=5udlM2IBjfxtKM%3A&w=736&h=736&itg=1&bih=921&biw=1887&ved=0ahUKEwiHgabKyoTNAhUVHlIKHdkDBeIQMwgeKAEwAQ&iact=mrc&uact=8)